# Flash AIR app's (Desktop) performance considerably worse than same code compiled as Flash Projector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, projector

I've created a Flash application (AS3) in CS6 (Mac) that performs as expected when published as a Flash Projector. But when I publish as an AIR app (v3.4.0.2540) the app's performance is about 50% worse than the Projector. I set it to use GPU Hardware Acceleration, render mode is Auto. Are there other settings I should be using? The performance hits come at expected times (when using MOUSE_MOVE and ENTER_FRAME listeners), but it works fine in the stand alone player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting render mode to auto will cause AIR to [fall back to the CPU](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffd.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d1298b2f93a0-7ffc) (see "renderMode"). If you are relying on the GPU (you didn't state whether you are or not but it is implied) this would likely cause significant performance degradation.

You need to set render mode to `direct` or `gpu` to take advantage of the GPU in AIR. I'm not entirely certain what the difference is but I've always used `direct` when working with Starling.

Another thing to consider with AIR: are you publishing a release build or a debug build? Debug builds perform considerably worse than release builds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try changing the rendering mode to Direct. In the meantime I tested on a PC and it ran much better. Mac + Adobe = Stupid.

Comment: @kenecaswell Oh yeah. AIR on Mac is not nearly as fast as on Win in my experience, though I've always found it passable.

Comment: Use "direct". "GPU" is the old GPU mode. It means it uses the GPU semi-automatically to perform standard Flash composition, such as drawing bitmaps. Sometimes this is desirable, some times this is disastrous (e.g. using things like scrollRect has a huge penalty in performance). So when using Starling and "real" GPU compositing with Stage3d and the alike, it should always be "direct".